# Scoped type variables in typeclass methods vs. standalone functions

Tags: haskell

Here is short example. I wonder why in TypeClass example I don't have to explicitly say `forall` while in function definition without `forall` it fails to compile with:

```
Couldn't match kind ‘Nat’ with ‘*’
    When matching types
      proxy0 :: Nat -> *
      Proxy :: * -> *
    Expected type: proxy0 n0
      Actual type: Proxy p0
    In the first argument of ‘natVal’, namely ‘(Proxy :: Proxy p)’
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘natVal (Proxy :: Proxy p)’
    In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely
      ‘(show $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy p))’
```

Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RoleAnnotations     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies        #-}

data Container (p :: Nat) (k :: Nat) = Container { first :: [Int], second :: [Int] }

instance (KnownNat p, KnownNat k) => Show (Container p k) where
  show c  = "Container " ++ (show $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy p)) ++ 
                     " " ++ (show $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy k))

showMe :: forall p k . (KnownNat p, KnownNat k) => Container p k -> String
showMe c = "Container " ++ (show $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy p)) ++ 
                    " " ++ (show $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy k))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ScopedTypeVariables` brings type variables in instance heads into scope in the instance bodies without an explicit `forall`. That doesn't happen for type signatures; instead you must use `forall` to bring `p` and `k` into scope in the definition of `showMe`.